# Asus "out of range" when i selected debian from the grub nvidia

Tags: drivers, debian, display, grub, nvidia-graphics-card

Some weeks ago, I installed Debian with grub on secondary ssd. Now when I selected Debian on my monitor show an text "out of range".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the monitor not being able to display the requested resolution/refresh rate.

You will need to boot Debain into a recovery mode to change the resolution to one that is suitable for the machine. If you have a working OS on the same hardware, it would be worth your time checking the settings, so you know what you can use.